# How to check a number or decimal or string would translate to an integer without round up

Tags: php, floating-point, integer, isnumeric

How to check a number or decimal or string would translate to an integer without round up?
e.g:

```
$value = 15.00000 // true
$value= 15.00001 // false
$value = '15.00000' // true
$value= '15.00001' // false
$value = 0.00000 // true
$value= 0.00001 // false
$value = 2.3233 // false
$value = 'asd32.32' // false
$value = 1 // true
$value = 0 // true
$value = '1' // true
$value = '0' // true
```

only .00000 will count as true. other decimal with number in it will count as false

Comment: `if ($value == (int) $value) { ... }` perhaps? Though you might want to do an `is_numeric()` test first

Comment: but is_numeric(15.00001); and is_numeric(15.0000); are both true, what function are you using?

Comment: This will do, `$stat = is_numeric($value) && $value == (int)$value ? "true" : "false"; echo $stat;`

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if it's a number

```
is_numeric(Value)
```

and then do a modulo 1

```
Value % 1
```

Anything that doesn't return 0 or isn't numeric should return false, the rest is true.